# Why does React Context act differently to objects and arrays?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

So I am trying to build a basic theme changer app, but in midway I tried to put the object value.

This is the object that stores the stylesheet.

```
 const Theme = {
light:{
    textColor:"#000",
    backgroundColor:"#fff"
},
dark:{
    textColor:"#fff",
    backgroundColor:"#000"
}}
```

export default Theme;

Case 1: I tried using an array as default value in context and state

```
const themeContext = createContext(["light"]);
const theme = useContext(themeContext)[0];//theme is whatever is in context array
 const currentTheme = Theme[theme]//current theme will be the value of themecontext in 0th position in array
 const themeHook = useState("light"); //write theme in state, so when app starts it has a default theme at that time
```

Case 2: Now If I try to add default value as an object it does not work:

```
const themeContext = createContext(Theme.dark);
const theme = useContext(themeContext);
const currentTheme = theme;
const themeState = useState(Theme.dark);
```

I use this to access the data:

```
<h1
        style={{
                color:`${currentTheme.textColor}`,
                backgroundColor:`${currentTheme.backgroundColor}`
            }}
        >
        Hello Boiss
        
        </h1>
```

Can anyone tell why?

Comment: There is an exactly the same code in [an example in the React Documentation about Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#dynamic-context) that explains exactly how this works.

Comment: What exactly are you getting in currentTheme?. Ideally, it should work. 
But while using state it returns an array that I find is not proper in your code.
const [themeState, setThemeState] = useState(Theme.dark); <- It should be like this